# Hide empty group in Ag-grid after row update

Tags: grouping, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

How to remove empty groups from ag-grid after `updateRowData`. In the plnkr example, I am modifying country value for the row, I expect group name to be changed but instead a new group is created.

Code for modifying country name:

```
let toBeUpdate = [];

this.gridApi.forEachNode((rowNode, index) => {
  if(rowNode.data && rowNode.data.athlete == 'Sadiq Khoja'){

    var data = rowNode.data;
    data.country = 'AAA Unknown X';
    toBeUpdate.push(data);
  }
});

this.gridApi.updateRowData({update:toBeUpdate});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/PTuwR5zejS2xiLIg

(Press 'Add' button to change the country name)

Answer (score 0):

UpdateRowData works when there is no row group.
In this case, instead of using updateRowData try using setRowData -
this.gridApi.setRowData(toBeUpdate);

This will also refresh the grid to reflect the changes in the row.

For more information you can read here - https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/data-update/

Comment: this also works but is there a way to avoid collapsing all groups after calling `setRowData`?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to update your data would be to use the `setDataValue` on `rowNode` (see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/data-update-single-row-cell/)).

Once you update your data, you need to refresh your view for grouping via the api by calling `refreshClientSideRowModel`.

So your update funciton should be as follows:

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode((rowNode, index) => {
  if(rowNode.data && rowNode.data.athlete == 'Sadiq Khoja'){
    rowNode.setDataValue('country', 'AAA Unknown X');
  }
});

this.gridApi.refreshClientSideRowModel('group');
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/vS0uZueP4pgGCosW)

Comment: this works but only problem is that it collapses all groups. I think refreshClientSideRowModel is causing that